# Disabling the Back Button in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In a Blazor based SPA, you must be able to stop the user navigating back using the back button in the browser.  However, I can't find any information about how to do this.

In classic ASPX this was relatively simple, but how do you do it on a Blazor Application/Page?  I've seen [NoCache] on Views, but that doesn't seem to apply to Blazor pages/components.  The javascript window.history.forward() option sort of works, but it refreshes the page, and thus loses the form changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Net7.0 this issue has been resolved by adding the new Navigation manager features.  There's an a question and answer here that demonstrates how to use the features in an edit form. - [Managing State and Preventing Blazor Navigation in an Edit Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75157902/managing-state-and-preventing-blazor-navigation-in-an-edit-form)

Answer (score 5):

Cancelling the navigation is not yet supported. See github issues :

- [Support canceling of navigation](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5620)
- [New event for NavigationManger](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14962)

### .Net 7 Update

Since .Net 7 you can use `NavigationManager.RegisterLocationChangingHandler` with `LocationChangingContext.PreventNavigation`  :

```cs
NavigationManager.RegisterLocationChangingHandler(async context =>
{
    if (!EditContext.IsModified())
    {
        return;
    }

    var isConfirmed = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("window.confirm", Localizer["Are you sure you want to leave this page?"]?.ToString())
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (!isConfirmed)
    {
        context.PreventNavigation();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I sort of guessed that was the case.

Comment: can you help me how to detect a page refersh in blazor server?

Comment: Watch out, do not use NavigationManager.RegisterLocationChangingHandler without unregistering it, as otherwise it is new registered on each page load. It returns an IDisposable which should be handled

Comment: @Zohair: you could use something like this to detect if your on the same page, just modify the string to your page name `bool pageRefresh = context.TargetLocation.EndsWith("OverviewUsers");`

Answer (score 2):

I'm providing an answer to this question because it gets a lot of views: that suggests a lot of people are searching for an answer to the question.

Since I first asked the question I've worked on various solutions.  There's no perfect solution, but I've put together a [Gist here](https://gist.github.com/ShaunCurtis/b24eec63cd004a5c5b226f914f831ab0).  The solution is far too big for a StackOverflow answer.