# Managing State and Preventing Blazor Navigation in an Edit Form

Tags: blazor

If you have a dirty form i.e. the data has been edited, you don't want to allow users to navigate away from the form.

In a Blazor Form the edit state maintained by the `EditContext` is simplistic.  Change a field to a new value, and then revert to the old value, and `EditContext` still believes the field has changed.

You can code disabling the Exit button within the form, but how do you prevent navigation though menu links and say the back button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read data from a data source such as an API, the data you receive is read only.  Treat it as immutable, using `record` objects rather than `class` objects to represent the data.

This is my demo record.  It's a simple record of the name and registration code for a country.  All the properties are declared as immutable.

```cs
public record DboCountry
{
    public Guid Uid { get; init; }
    public string Name { get; init; } = string.Empty;
    public string Code { get; init; } = string.Empty;
}
```

We can generate a simple dummy data pipeline for this record with get and save async methods that would normally make API calls.

```cs
public interface ICountryDataBroker
{
    public ValueTask<DboCountry> GetItemAsync(Guid uid);
    public ValueTask<bool> SaveItemAsync(DboCountry item);
}

public class CountryAPIDataBroker
{
    // Normally inject the HttpClient 
    public CountryAPIDataBroker() { }

    public async ValueTask<DboCountry> GetItemAsync(Guid uid)
    {
        // Emulate getting record from the API
        await Task.Delay(500);
        return new() { Uid = uid, Name = "United Kingdom", Code = "UK" };
    }

    public async ValueTask<bool> SaveItemAsync(DboCountry item)
    {
        // Emulate saving the record to the API
        await Task.Delay(500);
        return true;
    }
}
```

We need an editable version of `DboCountry`.  This is where using  `record` objects comes into it's own.  Cloning and equality checking is easy.  We save a copy of the original record used to create the record and use this to test state by comparing it against a record we generate dynamically from the current values.  You can add validation to this class or build the necessary fluid validation classes from it.  I've added Fluent Validation to demonstrate,

```cs
public class CountryEditContext
{
    public Guid Uid { get; private set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Code { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public DboCountry BaseRecord { get; private set; } = new DboCountry();
    public bool IsDirty => BaseRecord != this.AsRecord;

    public CountryEditContext(DboCountry record) 
        => this.Load(record);

    public void Reset()
        => this.Load(this.BaseRecord);

    public void Load(DboCountry record) 
    {
        this.BaseRecord = record with { };
        this.Uid= record.Uid;
        this.Name= record.Name;
        this.Code= record.Code;
    }

    public DboCountry AsRecord
        => new DboCountry
        {
            Uid= this.Uid,
            Name= this.Name,
            Code= this.Code,
        };
}
```

Next our Presentation layer service.

This holds and manages the data used by the edit form.  The `CountryEditContext` is readonly so can't be replaced during the lifetime of the presenter.  The presenter is a `Transient` service, so it's important not to do anything in it that requires implementing `IDisposable`.

```cs
public class CountryEditorPresenter
{
    private ICountryDataBroker _broker;

    public readonly CountryEditContext Record = new CountryEditContext(new());

    public CountryEditorPresenter(CountryDataBroker broker)
        => _broker = broker;

    public async ValueTask<bool> GetItemAsync(Guid uid)
    {
        var record = await _broker.GetItemAsync(uid);
        //Logic to check we got a record
        this.Record.Load(record);
        return true;
    }

    public async ValueTask<bool> SaveItemAsync()
    {
        await _broker.SaveItemAsync(this.Record.AsRecord);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The services are registered as follows:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICountryDataBroker, CountryAPIDataBroker>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<CountryEditorPresenter>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IValidator<CountryEditContext>, CountryValidator>();
```

Finally the edit form.  It's a normal form with the button state controlled by the record edit state.

The form locking is accomplished by:

1. Wiring the NavigationManager's `RegisterLocationChangingHandler` to a handler that prevents/allows navigation based on the form state.  This prevents intra SPA navigation.
2. Adding a `NavigationLock` component to the form and wiring it up to the form state. This prevents external navigation including using the back button.

```html
@page "/"
@inject CountryEditorPresenter Presenter
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<EditForm EditContext=_editContext>
    <FluentValidationValidator DisableAssemblyScanning="@true" />
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label class="form-label">Country</label>
        <BlazrInputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="this.Presenter.Record.Name"/>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => this.Presenter.Record.Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label class="form-label">Code</label>
        <BlazrInputText class="form-control" @bind-Value=this.Presenter.Record.Code />
        <ValidationMessage For="() => this.Presenter.Record.Code" />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2 text-end">
        <button class="btn btn-success" disabled="@(!this.Presenter.Record.IsDirty)" @onclick="this.Save">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" disabled="@(!this.Presenter.Record.IsDirty)" @onclick="this.ExitWithoutSave">Exit Without Saving</button>
        <button class="btn btn-dark" disabled="@(this.Presenter.Record.IsDirty)" @onclick="this.Exit">Exit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2">
        <ValidationSummary />
    </div>
</EditForm>

<NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation="this.Presenter.Record.IsDirty"  />
```

```cs
@code {
    private EditContext _editContext = default!;
    private IDisposable? _navLockerDispose;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _editContext = new EditContext(Presenter.Record);
        await Presenter.GetItemAsync(Guid.NewGuid());
        _navLockerDispose = NavManager.RegisterLocationChangingHandler(this.CheckFromState);
    }

    private ValueTask CheckFromState(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        if (this.Presenter.Record.IsDirty)
            context.PreventNavigation();

        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task Save()
        => await this.Presenter.SaveItemAsync();

    private Task Exit()
    {
        // Exit to where?
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task ExitWithoutSave()
    {
        this.Presenter.Record.Reset();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
        => _navLockerDispose?.Dispose();
}
```

#### For reference

This is `RazrInputText`:

```html
@namespace Blazr.EditForm
@inherits InputText

<input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
       class="@CssClass"
       @bind="CurrentValueAsString"
       @bind:event="oninput" />
```

This is `CountryValidator`:

```cs
public class CountryValidator : AbstractValidator<CountryEditContext>
{
    public CountryValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.Name)
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("You must enter a Name")
        .MaximumLength(50).WithMessage("Name cannot be longer than 50 characters");

        RuleFor(p => p.Code)
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("You must enter a Code for the Country")
        .MaximumLength(4).WithMessage("A country code is 1, 2, 3 or 4 letters");
    }
}
```

Note that the navigation features used to prevent navigation are new to Net7.0.

Comment: Any idea how to preven naigation .net6 maui blazor app

Comment: Well done. Maybe one day we can have nice things like this will a lot less ceremony.