# Blazor Location Changed

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I am using Blazor and C#. I am trying to get confirmation dialog when I try to leave the page, only if there are unsaved changes on it. I am adding unsaved items in EditedItems list, and I want to achieve to get confirmation dialog only if this list is not null.
I tried this way:

```
protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("myfun", EditedItems.Any());
        if(firstRender)
        { ...
        }
```

}

```
public async Task SaveList()
    {
        await Mediator.Send(new UpdateEditedItems(EditedItems));
        EditedItems.Clear();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

But I have problem because after saving, function OnAfterRenderAsync is called before it clears the list in SaveList function. How can I fix that? Or can you recommend me other solution?

Comment: https://blazor-university.com/routing/detecting-navigation-events/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.routing.navigationlock?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @RobertHarvey this is only for .net7 :( I'm using .net6

Comment: @e_taylor if you have clearance to do so, upgrading to .NET 7 from 6 is rather easy as they all are Core at the end of the day. [This may help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/60-70?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I upgraded specifically to .NET 7 to get this functionality.  Trying to do it in the .NET 6 version of Blazor would have been a pretty heavy lift.

Comment: [Polite] Your code makes little sense.  Your first block calls some unknown js function called `myfun`.  Your second calls does a bit of work and calls StateHasChanged.  There is no context here, no indication of how you are tracking state and no indication of how you are trying to stop navigation.

Comment: This answer provides some information on how to control Navigation in the EditForm context which may/may not be of use to you. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75157902/managing-state-and-preventing-blazor-navigation-in-an-edit-form