# How do I refresh/reload a Blazor Server EditForm back to new state like Ajax Update Panel used to?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-editform

I have a comments form:
[image]

When the user clicks the button, I need it to reload the form without reloading the page; exactly as the `<asp:updatepanel>` would, looking like the screenshot once the user clicks the button. I have been searching for days and have found nothing about how to accomplish this simple task. I know Blazor Server takes over a lot of work that UpdatePanel did, but I can't find how to do this.

My EditForm:

```
<EditForm Model="@commentForm" Context="CommentsContext" OnValidSubmit="Comments">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xxl-12 d-flex justify-content-lg-center align-items-lg-center justify-content-xl-center align-items-xl-center justify-content-xxl-center align-items-xxl-center">
            <DxMemo 
                CssClass="cw-480"
                ResizeMode="MemoResizeMode.Disabled"
                Rows="5" 
                Columns="200"
                ClearButtonDisplayMode="DataEditorClearButtonDisplayMode.Auto" 
                NullText="Enter your comment..."
                @bind-Text="commentForm.CommentText" >
            </DxMemo>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center justify-content-sm-end align-items-sm-center justify-content-md-end align-items-md-center justify-content-lg-end justify-content-xl-end justify-content-xxl-end align-items-xxl-center">
            <DxButton SubmitFormOnClick=true Text="Save Comment" style="font-size:20px; border-radius:6px;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

Here is the simple function I have for OnValidSubmit:

```
CommentFormModel commentForm { get; set; } = new CommentFormModel();
public EditContext CommentsContext { get; set; }

public async Task Comments() {
    commentText = commentForm.CommentText;
    CommentsContext = new EditContext(commentForm);
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

I am using DevExpress. However EditForm is a Blazor component. I'll do whatever is needed. I just need this functionality.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple demo page.  It uses the base Blazor controls, DevEx costs money.  It shows how to set up and reset the edit model and the `EditContext`.

I've saved the model to a list: you will obviously do something more permanent.

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Comment on this Site</h1>


<EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="this.Save">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <InputTextArea class="form-control mb-3" @bind-Value=_editComment.Comment placeholder="Enter a comment, don't hold back!" />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="text-end">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" >Save</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

<div>
    @foreach(var comment in _comments)
    {
        <pre>@comment.Comment</pre>
    }

</div>

@code {
    private List<CommentData> _comments = new();
    private EditContext? _editContext;
    private CommentData _editComment = new();

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _editContext = new EditContext(_editComment);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task Save()
    {
        //Fake a async database save
        await Task.Delay(100);
        _comments.Add(_editComment);

        // Reset the edit context
        _editComment = new();
        _editContext = new EditContext(_editComment);
    }


    public class CommentData
    {
        public Guid Uid { get; init; } = Guid.NewGuid();

        [Required]
        public string? Comment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is precisely what I'm looking for and it works! Thank you!!!

Comment: NP.  This is very simplistic.  See this question and answer for a more realistic example of form editing..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75157902/managing-state-and-preventing-blazor-navigation-in-an-edit-form