# Blazor Server - Disable browser back button .NET6

Tags: asp.net-core, browser, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I come from an ASP.NET webforms background and now learning Blazor Server.  I have an application that is in testing and I need a way to disable the browser's back button.  In ASP.NET this was very simple.  I have been researching and have seen that .NET 7 has some new offerings using the Navigation Manager however, we are using .NET 6 and cannot upgrade the framework at this point.  Is there a way to do this in .NET 6, perhaps on the MainLayout page or would it have to be done on each page?  It would only really need to be on the page(s) where we have EditForms.

Thanks for any help,
Jim

Comment: Hi @JimboJones, the js code `window.history.forward()` can achieve your requirement, but if you want to maintain your current changed form data, you need check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75157903/11398810).

Comment: Thank you
Would I put this in _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: You can't disable the browser's back button.  (other than prompting onbeforeunload, which is pretty goofy)  You can control what URLs go into the navigation history, though.

Comment: Hi @JimboJones, yes, of course you can.